# Import error pycrypto google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, importerror

I'm running a local server in Python with GAE, and importing a 3rd party library, which in turn imports pycrypto. I installed it locally using pip and included it in my app.yaml file, but when I run the server, I get the following error:

`ImportError: cannot import name OSRNG`

Here's what my app.yaml looks like:

```
runtime: python27
threadsafe: 1

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: pycrypto
  version: "latest"
```

I'm running homebrew python 2.7.

Comment: Can you include the full traceback? And maybe your code snippet triggering it?

Comment: was this answered? I am struggling with the same error.

Answer (score 1):

The *pycrypto* library is built-in in the runtime environment, however you need to install it locally in order to run the local development server, as you did. It might just be a problem with versions, as the [supported *pycrypto* versions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/built-in-libraries-27) are **2.3**, **2.6** and **2.6.1**.

Try installing the proper version with `pip install pycrypto==2.6.1`.

Then, change your *app.yaml* file to the appropriate version:

```
libraries:
- name: pycrypto
  version: "2.6.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

[Official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#api_version) seems to suggest that `api_version` in `app.yaml` is required.

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was that google app engine uses its own python installation (in my case in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython2\python.exe").

Once I installed pycrypto using that path, it worked fine:

```
.\python.exe -m pip install pycrypto
```

NOTE! Need to run cmd/powershell as administrator!