# Python Appengine - "ImportError: cannot import name OSRNG" when invoking the Endpoints tool

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, pycrypto

I am following [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/get-started-frameworks-python#before-you-begin) on Google Cloud Endpoints. I am having trouble at the "Generating the OpenApi configuration file" section. Specifically, when I invoke the Endpoints tool.

The [Traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0Aou.jpg) is saying that the file on lib/Crypto/Random/**init**.py "from Crypto.Random import OSRNG" is producing the import error.

What I have done so far

1. Looked at the path lib/Crypto/Random and saw a folder named OSRNG - thus made sure that there was a folder called OSRNG (I didnt see any py file name OSRNG.py though)
2. Followed the answer for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34944968/importerror-cannot-import-name-osrng-when-importing-gcloud-storage-in-google) question by putting the pycrypto version to "latest" in the app.yaml file.
3. Looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14850853/how-to-include-third-party-python-libraries-in-google-app-engine) question but doesnt apply.
4. Looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47641437/import-error-pycrypto-google-app-engine) question by specifying the version rather than "latest" in app.yaml.

I don't understand why it is saying there is an import error when I can literally see the package/module in the directory.

Can someone help why it is producing an import error?

Comment: What is the result of this command? `echo $ENDPOINTS_GAE_SDK`. 

It should be `/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine`, as mentioned [in step 11](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/get-started-frameworks-python#before-you-begin).

Comment: hi @Mangu yeap, I did that. However, the sdk isnt installed in /usr/lib like yours. it is just installed in ~/home/gilho/ . Didn think that was a problem.

Comment: Did changing the location of the SDK solved the issue?

Comment: i will give it a go. Would be weird if it worked because the documentation said that it doesnt matter where the sdk is installed

Answer (score 0):

Are you running on OSX?
I encountered a similar problem and the solution for me was installing google-endpoints (which for some reason is missing from the instructions):

`pip install -t lib google-endpoints --ignore-installed`

Comment: Im running ubuntu. I did that (installing google-endpoints). still no luck.

Comment: I'm hitting the same problem:
echo $ENDPOINTS_GAE_SDK returns empty string

I've installed:
pip install -t lib google-endpoints --ignore-installed
in both -t lib
and in my local virtual env

not sure what to try next??